# Evaluating integrals such as $\int \frac{1+\cos^{2}x}{1+\cos2x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

We started integrals not too long ago, I understand it for the most part but I always have a problem figuring out how to solve ones involving trig identities. Like this:

$$\int \frac{1+\cos^{2}x}{1+\cos2x}$$

Indefinite integral of $$\frac{ 1 + \cos^2(x)}{ 1 + \cos(2x) }.$$

I tried changing the denominator to $2\cos^2(x)$ but I still can't make a u substitution.

Comment: $\frac{1+\cos^2 x}{\cos^2 x}=\sec^2 x+1$.

Comment: It's a good idea to internalize (memorize) some of the identities such as this one. Be it trig identities, or exponential identities and geometric series formulae etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$1+\cos{2x}=2 \cos^2{x}$$

$$1/\cos^2{x}=\frac{d}{dx} \tan{x}$$

That should get you across the finish line.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about the derivative of tanx.
I got $\frac {tanx}{2} + \frac {x}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{1+\cos^2x}{1+\cos2x}dx=\int \frac{1+\cos^2x}{2\cos^2x} dx=\frac12\int(\sec^2x+1)dx=\frac12(\tan x+x)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $$2\cos^2x = 1+ \cos2x$$
$$\cos^2x= \frac{1+ \cos2x}{2}$$
$$=∫1+\frac{1+ \cos2x}{2} * \frac{1}{1+\cos2x} $$
$$=\int\frac{1}{1+\cos2x}+\int\frac{1}{2}$$
Use $$u=2x$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}[\int\frac{1}{1+\cos(u)}]+\frac{1}{2}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}[\int\frac{1-cos(u)}{1-\cos^2u}]$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}[\int\frac{1-cos(u)}{\sin^2u}]$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}[\int\frac{1 }{\sin^2u}du -\int\frac{\cos u}{\sin^2u}du]$$
Use $$v=\sin u$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}[-\cot u + \frac{1}{\sin u}]$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}[-\cot 2x + \frac{1}{\sin 2x}]$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\tan x$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\tan x+\frac{1}{2}x$$